# Probability Conundrum -- Spot The Error edition

Tags: probability

Where is (are) the error(s) in the following argument? If you can spot it and explain, please do.

**Problem**: Suppose Alice chooses two real numbers, A and B, and writes them down on pieces of paper. She places the pieces of paper face down on a table, where you are allowed to choose one. Your job is to guess whether the other number, which you are not allowed to see, is larger or smaller than the one you chose.

**Claim**: There is a method by which you have greater than 50% chance of guessing correctly.

Say you choose A. Then randomly select a number x from any continuous probability distribution of the real numbers whose density function F(x) is non-zero on all of R (such as the standard normal distribution). Assume that x is between A and B, and base your guess about B on this assumption. You should be correct in your guess (slightly) more than 50% of the time.

**Explanation**: Either you are right about x or not. First, what if you are right?

**A < X < B**

**B < X < A**

For the first case, you will correctly guess that B is larger than A. In the second case, you will correctly guess that B is less than A. Either way, if x is between A and B, you will guess correctly.

Next, what if you are not right about x? There are four cases.

**A < B < X**

**B < A < X**

**X < A < B**

**X < B < A**

First: You will be correct that B is larger than A.

Second: You will guess that B is less than A, but you will be wrong.

Third: You will guess that B is larger than A, but you will be wrong.

Last: You will be correct that B is less than A.

Therefore, if you are wrong about x, then you will be right about B half of the time. If you are right about x, then you will always be right about B. Since F(x) is non-zero, then you have a non-zero chance that you will be right about x. So, you should be right about B more than ½ of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore, if you are wrong about x, then you will be right about B half of the time.

This doesn't follow automatically. The fact that there are four different cases doesn't imply all cases occur with equal probability.

Other than that, I think your argument works. See also the [strategy here](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/02/09/math-puzzle/comment-page-1/#comments) for this problem.